# Mongoose Cast to ObjectId failed for value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have following schema in mongoose

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: { type: String, unique: true },

});
var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
var ReviewSchema = new Schema({
  schoolId: String,
  firstname: String,
  image_url: String,
  lastname: { type: String },
  email: String,
  rating: Number,
  review: String,
  time: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  updated_at: Date,
  voters: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }]

});


var Review = mongoose.model('Review', ReviewSchema);


module.exports = Review;
```

and following code in nodejs

```
app.post("/like", function (req, res) {
    var query = { id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.id) };
    var voter = { email: req.body.email };
    var update = { $push: { 'voters': voter } };
    var options = { upsert: true, 'new': true };

    Review.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options, function (err, doc) {
        console.log(err);
        res.end("done");
    });
});
```

When I am sending request to above method I am getting following error message

```
 { [CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "[object Object]" at path "voters"]
     message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "[object Object]" at path "voters"',
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have `voters` defined as an `ObjectId` ref, but you're trying to store an actual `User` representation inside it.

Assuming I understand your links correctly, you'll want to lookup the `_id` of the `User` by `req.body.email`, then make your update `{ $push: { voters: userId } }` (where `userId` is the id of the `User` you found).

Comment: I am finding review by id and then I am pushing email address to voters array

Comment: If you want to store the email address on the voters array, you'll have to modify your definition to store the object itself, instead of a reference to the `User` model. The way you have it right now, your model should be storing `User._id` inside `Review.voters[]`.

Comment: If I am not wrong voters should be defined as with voters : [UserSchema ]

Comment: I think you can do that. Truth be told, I've never actually attempted to re-use a schema as an internal schema as well as a directly exported model at the same time, but I imagine it should work. If you run into problems with pointers or something, you could also define a `ReviewVoterSchema` that also holds an `{ email }` field.

Comment: After making this changes in ReviewSchema  voters: { type : Array , "default" : [] }  there is not error but now problem is it's creating seprate document instead of updating the original one

Comment: Which separate document? A separate User or a separate Review? If you want to store the `email` with the `Review`, then you have to have a separate document. If you want to keep it normalized / relational, then you have to store the `User._id` on the `Review` instead.

Comment: Its creating a new document because its not able to find the document using the query `var query = { id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.id) };`, since mongoDb stored ids in the field `_id`. Update your query with `var query = { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.id) }`